# Efficient way to overwrite data present in a row of a table

Tags: sql, jsp

I have a requirement where I need to overwrite a row present in a table with the data from a different row of the same table. The unique column of the table is the insertionorderid. This table has 53 columns ( excluding the insertionorderid column). So I fetch all the data from the 53 columns using a long select query from the first row and then update them to the second row. Is there a better way or a more efficient way to do this operation?

Comment: Please provide table structure, sample data and desired results. Also it would be good to mention what DBMS you are using

Comment: You method is fine.  The alternative is basically to delete the row and re-insert it.